# Несколько virtualenv в одном проекте

Tags: python, pycharm, микросервисы

Есть проект, содержащий несколько микросервисов с тестами для каждого из них.

Каждый микросервис имеет свои зависимости. Тесты тоже имеют свои зависимости.

Как можно для каждого из них создать свой изолированный venv и удобно переключаться между ними при работе в PyCharm?

Единственное решение, что нашёл, это делать много проектов, и переключаться между окнами.

Есть ли лучший способ?

Comment: В случаи тестов, можно в bat указывать из какого venv запускать какой скрипт-тест

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В PyCharm в рамках одного проекта может быть сконфигурирован только один virtualenv.

Открывайте дополнительные проекты не в новом окне, а присоединяйте к текущему. Тогда у вас будут сразу все проекты в одном окне PyCharm и один из них выбран как главный (в англ. версии primary project).

С отдельными virtualenv-ами для тестов в рамках одного проекта нужно создать интерпретаторы для двух virtualenv и переключаться между ними. Это можно делать глобально в настройках проекта, а также в настройках конфигураций запуска. Т.е. указать, что, например, для запуска тестов использовать интерпретатор с virtualenv с зависимостями тестов:
[image: Настройка интепретатора для запуска тестов в PyCharm]